# Image control not shown in Pivot Item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to put some controls inside a `Grid`, which is situated in a pivot item.
Everything I have added so far is shown, however the picture control with a default picture is not visible.

I can see the picture control with the loaded default pic in the design editor, but not when the application is run.

When the application is launched, only the button and the ellipse are visible.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<phone:Pivot HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" Grid.Row="1" Title="pivot" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480">
        <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Home" Margin="10,10,-235,-578">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="576" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438">
                <Image Source="Images/DefaultProfilePic.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="32,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="32,292,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Search">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="My Profile">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: Are the images also copied to the deployed version?

Comment: Yes, the picture is coppied to the folder "Images". I have imported it through "Add existing item" in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah but when you click on the images properties you can set `Copy to Output Directory`

Comment: try this  `<Image Source="/Images/DefaultProfilePic.jpg" />`

Comment: I set both coppy to output directory and `<Image Source="/Images/DefaultProfilePic.jpg" />`. And it worked! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `Images` folder is inside the `Assets` folder then try this.

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Images/DefaultProfilePic.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="32,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

or If the `Images` is a child folder of your project like `Assets`, then use this

```
<Image Source="/Images/DefaultProfilePic.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="32,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```